# Can I upgrade my ubuntu version and change to be primary OS after originally installing with Wibu?

Tags: upgrade, wubi

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi 12.04 and I now wish to upgrade to a full installation of Ubuntu 14.04, Before attempting to upgrade through the update center I did some research on upgrading from a Wubi installation (alongside windows) to a full installation making Ubuntu primary and only OS and found that it is in fact doable through the update center however it is just highly recommended to perform a full backup before doing so. I have now finished backing up all the data I need to worry about and began the upgrade process through the update center and received the following error:

Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 14.04.

Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?

My questions are as follows: A. Isnt 14.04 a LTS version??? B, What are your recomendations in order to ensure my graphics driver is installed correctly and im not stuck with bad configs/install?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When it comes to the error it is saying that 14.04, although an lts release, does not have unity2d as you are probably using on your current computer with 12.04, and would have to try and run a full unity3d environment with software acceleration instead of hardware. What are your computer's specs? Also to make it a primary installation you can download boot-repair (google it for instructions on doing so) and elect to install it in the mbr of your drive, then update grub. It will most likely have ubuntu as the default boot option and may even have an option to boot windows below it. If you want to just use ubuntu after that, just delete the windows partition (after backing up everything you want to save) then run `sudo update-grub /dev/sd<letter of the primary drive, not a subpartition>` then resize the ubuntu partition(s) CAREFULLY with gparted to take up the full disk.

Comment: My specs are really low this is a very old desktop that I am basically just using as like my secondary play machine. Acording to Ubuntu there is only 1.2 GB of RAM (really theres 2 GBs I believe) and a 2.53GHz intel celeron with 36 GB of of available disk space but I think the HDD is 60 or 80 GB. What are the minimum requirements for unity3d? Would it maybe be best to just reinstall 12.04 as a primary OS to improve performance?

Comment: I think unity needs a good graphics card to run 3d on the older releases, not just a lot of ram or fast hard drive or even a fast cpu

Comment: my advice is to upgrade but then boot and don't login normally but open a terminal with ctrl+alt+f1 and install some other desktop environment that isn't as intensive like lxde, xfce, or if you can live with a little stuttering kde

Comment: Ok so just upgrade through the update manager GUI and ignore the warning and once complete open a terminal at the login screen via alt+f1 and install a different desktop enviornment via commands through the terminal? How about switching the desktop to gnome? I will research how to switch to lxde desktop in the meantime.

Comment: Gnome desktop is not included by default and gnome 3 is as resource intensive as unity but I'd try kde to start

Comment: ok thank you and do I need to worry about being able to access boot-repair or will upgrading from the update center properly install 14.04 as primary OS (other then desktop issue obviously)?

Comment: it will install it as the primary os or in the layout it was last with grub. also if I helped go ahead and mark my answer as "the one" :)

Comment: so I took the plunge and upgraded to 14.04 which took like over 24 hourss to do for some reason and then after it finished upgrading and doing the cleanup it neveer rebooted and just hung there so I unfortunately had to force the PC down. AFter doing so I attempted to boot to ubuntu and booted to that infafrs prompt or w/e and could not get the desktop to load or boot into Ubuntu at all to start installing KDE. Luckily had still had my 14.04 install on my USB drive so I just decided to do a full installation via booting to that thumb drive and have also installed KDE.